# The expression "back to the envelope calculation", what does it mean?

Tags: terminology

I'm french and one of my teacher use often the expression : "back to the envelope calculation", but I don't find any satisfactory translation. If someone know the french, and a good translation of this expression, I would by happy to know it.

Comment: I believe the expression is "back *of* the envelope", and it refers to the fact that you scribble something fast on the closest piece of paper you can find.

Comment: Sounds like basic calculation by saying it repeatedly

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-of-the-envelope_calculation.

Comment: I've seen people use "au dos d'une enveloppe" but if memory serves it is always put in quotations which suggests that there isn't really a French equivalent.

Comment: back OF the envelope